# Как определить часть речи слова без учитывания контекста(просто определить часть речи слова) предложения?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

Как определить часть речи слова без учитывания контекста(просто определить часть речи слова) предложения?

Comment: С помощью учебника русского языка составить словари (списки) слов, определенных частей речи и проверять по ним. Но это практически нереально в условиях задачи, поэтому посмотрите уже готовые образцы: https://m.habr.com/ru/post/125988/

Comment: Есть библиотека `pymorphy2`, имеющая такие словари :)